# Get only numbers from strings that are in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have list that looks like this

```
mylist = ['storeitem_1','storeitem_2','storeitem_3']
```

How would I go about getting only numbers from those strings? I tried following but it came out totally wrong.

```
for items in mylist:
  print(items.split("storeitem_"))
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with a regex:

```
import re

mylist = ['storeitem_1','storeitem_2','storeitem_3']

re.findall('\d+', '|'.join(mylist))
```

Which gives:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Alternatively, something more along the lines of what you were trying:

```
[i.split('_')[-1] for i in mylist]
```

Gives you the same:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
num_list = [re.search(r'\d+', x)[0] for x in mylist]
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `mylist` always contains strings in the form of 'storeitem_n' where n is an integer from 0 to 9

You can do this to get n:

```
mylist = ['storeitem_1','storeitem_2','storeitem_3']

for items in mylist:
  print(items[-1])
```

Comment: This will fail at 2 any digit number

Comment: agreed but I'm just going off what he provided, i'll edit it to make that clearer